# mini test - testing an application controller method without render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a very simple Application controller method I want to test. It will be used by other application controller methods to determine if we need to redirect. So it isn't going to be doing any `render` functions.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def has_consent
    current_user ? current_user.consent : nil
  end
end
```

All the examples for mini-test use `#assert_response` or `#assert_redirected_to`. How do I get access to `application_controller` methods within the mini-test framework? IE, I can write the test, but how the heck do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is you don't.

The public API of a controller is the actions that respond to HTTP requests and you test them by sending HTTP requests and writing assertions about the response returned.

If your method does not respond to HTTP requests it should be a private method. **And you don't test privates.**

Rather you should test by testing how your application responds when the user has not given consent. Not the implementation details.

If testing the method in isolation is really important then it does not belong in the controller. Rather in the model layer or a helper - which can be tested in isolation.

Comment: Its fully possible by creating a mock controller class and extend it with ApplicationController - but its not a good idea.